# C++ std::atomic and shared memory?

Tags: c++11, gcc, memory, atomic

I have 4096 bytes of shared memory allocated. How to treat it as an array of `std::atomic<uint64_t>` objects?

The final goal is to place array of 64-bit variables to shared memory and perform `__sync_fetch_and_add` (GCC built-in) on these variables. But I would prefer using native C++11 code instead of using GCC built-ins. So how to use the allocated memory as an std::atomic objects? Should I invoke `placement new` on 512 counters? What If `std::atomic`'s constructor require additional memory allocations in some imeplementations? Should I consider the aligning of `std::atomic` object in shared memory?

Comment: This is one of the motivating cases for [Polymorphic Allocators] (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/lib_extensions#Polymorphic_allocators_and_memory_resources_2) - currently in experimental status.  Using this you could simply have containers allocated out of shared memory,

Comment: The only mention of shared memory in the C++ standard is exactly where it says lockfree std::atomics "should" be safe to use there.

Answer (score 1):

With C++20, you can use [std::atomic_ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref) if you can make sure that your objects are suitably aligned. For C++17 and anything older, boost::atomic_ref might work as well, though I haven't tested it.

If you don't want to use Boost, then compiler builtins are the only solution left. In that case, you should prefer the `__atomic` builtins over the old `__sync` functions, as stated [on the GCC documentation page for atomics](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html).